# How to learn which version of SSIS I use from SSDT

Tags: ssis

I have created a package, downloaded for that purpose `SSDT`, it came with `Visual Studio Shell 2015`.

How can I learn which version it is? 2012? 2016? I don't want to deploy it on any server. I just run it from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS, right click on the package in the solution explorer and select view code.  Then do a find for `LastModifiedProductVersion`.

- 2008 R2 = 10.50.X.X
- 2012 = 11.0.X.X
- 2014 = 12.0.X.X
- 2016 = 13.0.X.X